# Alcohol and athletes?

Tags: alcohol

I've seen a lot of articles claiming that alcohol has a very bad impact on athletic performance. Examples include, but are by far not limited to:

- http://oade.nd.edu/educate-yourself-alcohol/alcohol-and-athletes/
- http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/the-running-blog/2014/apr/23/how-does-alcohol-affect-athletic-performance
- https://www.acsm.org/docs/current-comments/alcoholandathleticperformance.pdf
- http://www.athletestore.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/The_Effect_of_Alcohol_on_Athletic_Performance.7.pdf

I'm of course not in position to doubt those articles, as I'm a no expert in biology.

However. There is one thing I find odd.

Namely. These articles themselves claim that alcohol is widely consumed even by the highest ranking athletes. I mean, if alcohol has that bad effects... then it couldn't have been consumed by highest-ranking athletes, as alcohol-consuming athletes could never rich the heights of the tops of proffessional sports?

Also. AFAIK mediaval knights were not abstinents by any means, they were drinking beer and wine and mead to excess; yet they were able to bring their strength, stamina, etc, to an extreme.

This is not something I wish to argue about; rather, this is something I fail to understand.

BTW. This question is not personal; I don't do sports and I very rarely drink. And I regret the former, not the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you look at any parameter in a population, you will have a spread. Let's take I.Q., for instance (and lets not quibble about how it's measured; it's irrelevant for our purposes):

[image]

This is the famous "bell shaped curve". You can see how few people are significantly above normal. Now, that line continues to include people with an I.Q. of 200+. That's not immediately obvious from the graph. It also continues the other way - people with an I.Q. so low that they cannot participate in their own testing. That's because the vast majority of people fall between 70 and 130.

The same principle applies to physical skill, bravery in battle, etc. The curve may be flattened or sharper depending on what parameter is being measured, but rest assured, paid professional athletes fall in the upper 1 percentile.

Lets go back to intelligence for a moment. Take someone like Bobby Fischer (Chess Player), I.Q.: 187

I guarantee you that **even falling-down drunk, Bobby Fischer would have beaten me easily in a game of chess** (and it's not because my I.Q. is average or below). It's because he was so very much, unimaginably better at chess than I am.

I guarantee you that **even falling-down drunk, Albert Einstein could solve mathematical equations I can't even write**. It's because he was so very much, unimaginably more intelligent than I am.

It's the same with great athletes. *Even if they drink every night, a great athlete will outperform you or me on any given day.*

That's why you are just dead wrong when you state "*then it couldn't have been consumed by highest-ranking athletes, as alcohol-consuming athletes could never rich the heights of the tops of proffessional sports*".

You are just laboring under a completely false premise. These people are so much better than people only 1 percentile below them that drinking doesn't necessitate that they fall in the ranks.

Comment: While a drunk Usain Bolt or Tiger Woods could beat me at their respective sports, the pro athletes etc are competing with others also at the extreme end of the bell curve, a gain of a small percentage does matter then.

Comment: @GriffinEvo - not if most of them are drinking, which they are. Alcohol use isn't a major factor for most top athletes.